# Need a dropdown list in django form from a model in another app

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

i have two apps in 1)boq 2)inputs
inputs has a model building

```
class building(models.Model):

    building = models.CharField(max_length=300
```

my boq app has a model boqmodel

```
class boqmodel(models.Model):
    code = models.IntegerField()
    building =models.CharField(max_length=300)
    level = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    activity = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    subactivity = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    duration=models.IntegerField()
    linkactivity= models.CharField(max_length=300)
    linktype= models.CharField(max_length=300)
    linkduration=models.IntegerField()
    plannedstart=models.DateField()
    plannedfinish=models.DateField()
    actualstart=models.DateField()
    actualfinish=models.DateField()
```

i have a form in boq app as follows

```
class boqform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = boqmodel
        fields = ['code',
                  'building',
                  'level',
                  'activity',
                  'subactivity',
                  'duration',
                  'linkactivity',
                  'linktype',
                  'linkduration',
                  'plannedstart',
                  'plannedfinish',
                  'actualstart',
                  'actualfinish']
```

Building column is same in boq and inputs app.

I need to have a drop down in boq form for building with values from model in inputs.building model

Comment: Why isn't it a ForeignKey, then?

Comment: Have you seen [ChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield)? And have you read [how to override the default fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) on a `ModelForm`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman i used a foriegn key.Now my BOQ model looks like this building=models.ForeignKey(building,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)   .  i am getting a dropdown list in form but the dropdown is filled with building.objects(1) and so instead of my inputs in table A-1

Comment: You need to define a `__str__` method on the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class building(models.Model):
    building = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.building

class boqmodel(models.Model):
    code = models.IntegerField()
    #building =models.CharField(max_length=300)
    building = models.ForeignKey(building, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    level = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    activity = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    subactivity = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    duration = models.IntegerField()
    linkactivity = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    linktype = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    linkduration = models.IntegerField()
    plannedstart = models.DateField()
    plannedfinish = models.DateField()
    actualstart = models.DateField()
    actualfinish = models.DateField()
```

**Done**